# Turn sequence of objects with collection into a flat sequence

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a sequence of events of type A.
A contains an enumeration of data objects B.
I would like to map sequence A into C so that it is a flat sequence of B.
How can I do that?

```
public class Sandbox
{
    public class A
    {
        public IEnumerable<B> Collection { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {

    }

    private readonly IObservable<A> _sequence;

    public Sandbox(IObservable<A> sequence)
    {
        _sequence = sequence;
    }

    public IObservable<B> C
    {
        get { return _sequence.Select(o =>  /* ... */); }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211809(v=vs.103).aspx) of `Observable.SelectMany`.  This takes a projection function that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

> Projects each element of an observable sequence to an observable sequence and flattens the resulting observable sequences into one observable sequence.

```
public IObservable<B> C
{
    get { return _sequence.SelectMany(o => o.Collection); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Enumerable.SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx), it takes a sequence of sequences and flattens them.

Answer (score 0):

You do want SelectMany but not the Enumerable SelectMany the [Observable.SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211809%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

```
public IObservable<B> C
{
    get { return _sequence.SelectMany(o =>  o.Collection); }
}
```